# unicode issue in python when writing to file

Tags: python, unicode

I have an csv sheet that i read it like this:

```
  with open(csvFilePath, 'rU') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter= '|')
        numberOfMovies = 0
        for row in reader:
            title = row[1:2][0]
```

as you see, i am taking the value of `title`

Then i surf the internet for some info about that value and then i write to a file, the writing is like this:

```
def writeRDFToFile(rdf, fileName):
    f = open("movies/" + fileName + '.ttl','a')
    try:
        #rdf = rdf.encode('UTF-8')
        f.write(rdf) # python will convert \n to os.linesep
    except:
        print "exception happened for movie " + movieTitle
    f.close()
```

In that function, i am writing the `rdf` variable to a file.

As you see there is a **commetted** line

If the value of rdf variable contains unicode char **and** that line was **not commeted**, that code doesn't write anything to the file.

However, if I just **commet** that line, that code writes to a file.

Okay you can say that: commit that line and everything will be fine, but that is not correct, because i have another **java** process (which is Fuseki server) that reads the file and if the file contains unicode chars, it throws an error.

so i need to solve the file myself, i need to encode that data to ut8,

help please

Comment: well, i don't know in english what is the correct word, commit, comment, commet.... but i mean when you put `#` before the line of code so the script doesn't consider that line of code

Comment: The correct word is _comment_. What is the type of data in `rdf`?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please [edit] your post and copy-paste the resulting program, along with any error message. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: And please clarify:  Do you need to remove unicode characters because the java server is expecting ascii only or do you need to create a file with valid unicode encoding?

Comment: @WombatPM i want a file with valid encoding encoding

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it is a data that has not assai chars, like ê ę ã â ª ç

Comment: What version of Python are you using? When you're talking about Unicode problems it makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

The normal csv library can have difficulty writing unicode to files. I suggest you use the [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1) library instead of the csv library. It supports writing unicode to CSVs.

Practically speaking, just write:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
```

Comment: I believe the normal `csv` library is better behaved in Python 3, right?

Comment: It isn't at all clear that he is writing a CSV file. He only claims to be reading a CSV file, he is writing a `.ttl` file, whatever that is.

Comment: When I did that, I got this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: invalid continuation byte` on line: `for row in reader:`

Comment: I had already changed reading the file to `reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter= '|', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: the value that makes the error is: `Misérables, Les`